# Does turning off cpu cores will actually save power?

Tags: battery-life, kernel, samsung-galaxy-j7, cpu

My phone is using custom kernel that has cpu hotplug in it. The hotplug name is AutoSMP and it has max cpu (big & little) core that should be online option in it. Currently I'm using 3 + 3 core configuration instead 4 + 4 core. Does it has impact on power consumption?

Note: big core is oc'ed to 1.79 ghz, stock is 1.58 ghz and little core I underclocked it to 1.35 ghz, stock freq is the same as big core.
gpu freq is oc'ed to 1.1 ghz, I think stock freq is 845 mhz for Exynos 7870.

Comment: search for this nice app [com.grarak.kerneladiutor](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2986129) you can play with

Comment: If no one is able to answer you here, I'd love to read your follow-up if you have time to run some experiments.

Comment: If you want to use developer tools: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/setup-battery-historian and I assume you've read/know about: [Relationship between CPU Usage and Battery Usage](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/167045/3573)